GitHub Actions script does not run
I created this GitHub Actions script to unpack any tar files that might be uploaded to a repository, but I am having some problems with it

The workflow does not trigger on push (I have tried both with tar and non-tar files)

When I manually trigger it, it does not unpack anything and gives me no errors

It does give me a warning

Node.js 16 actions are deprecated. Please update the following actions to use Node.js 20: actions/setup-node@v3. For more information see: https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/.

I read the post and I (hope) I updated the file accordingly, but the error persists.


name: Unpack tgz Files

on:
  push:
    paths:
      - '*.tgz'
  pull_request:
    paths:
      - '*.tgz'
  workflow_dispatch:  # Allow manual triggering of the workflow

jobs:
  unpack:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4
        with:
          node-version: '20'

      - name: Create /src directory if it doesn't exist
        run: mkdir -p src

      - name: List tgz files
        run: |
          echo "Listing tgz files in root directory:"
          ls *.tgz || echo "No tgz files found"

      - name: Extract tgz files
        run: |
          for tgzfile in *.tgz; do
            if [ -f "$tgzfile" ]; then
              dirname=$(basename "$tgzfile" .tgz)
              mkdir -p "src/$dirname"
              tar -xf "$tgzfile" -C "src/$dirname"
              echo "Unpacked $tgzfile into src/$dirname"
            fi
          done

I have also looked at these:

https://github.blog/changelog/2023-09-22-github-actions-transitioning-from-node-16-to-node-20/

GitHub Actions run on push to all branches

GitHub Action workflow not running


EDIT:
The output looks like this, but the /src folder is never created nor the file unzipped. I have also updated the code to use v4


EDIT 2:
I updated the code to (hopefully) check for .tzg files instead of .tar files (dumb mistake), but the src directory is still not created nor is the .tgz file unpacked
Edit 3:


Have you tried with 2 * like in this example ? : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpushpull_requestpull_request_targetpathspaths-ignore

Regarding the  Node.js 16 actions are deprecated warning, you can update the actions/setup-node@v3 to v4.

I have tried it with ```
paths:
- '**.tar'


@ArnaudFlaesch ohhh let me try that, thank you

that removed the warning (yay!) but it still didn't create anything (I realized I can't post images in the comments so I'll put them in the post please give me a second)

The *tar pattern won't work with a tgz file, you have to match the exact file extension

@ArnaudFlaesch oh my god you're so right that was so dumb let me see if changing it to *.tgz will fix it. I was also wondering if it is possible to handle both tar and tgz files by adding - '*.tgz' - '*.tar'

I guess you can try :
paths:
  - '**.tar'
  - '**.tgz'


I've updated the code (I think it's safer to stick to just .tgz until I learn more about this kind of stuff), but the output is still the same. Would it help to share the repository?

Is the workflow running now at least ? If you have a private repo, maybe just share the workflow logs, particularly the "List tgz files" step

The repo is at https://github.com/The-ION-Language/Actions-Testing (I made it public), I'll also put the screenshot in the post, also yes the workflow now runs ^^

Looks like the tgz is unpacked according to the logs

oh I see, do you know why I can not see the folder that's created (src), I don't think I delete it anywhere but I might be wrong

I'm not sure what you mean, but just in case the folder is created inside the workflow, it's not pushed to your repo

oh my bad, I assumed the folder would be created in the repository. I guess it makes sense that it isn't, maybe I'll just restructure it :/
Also, thanks so much for your help! and how would I mark your comment as the answer?

I'm in the middle of something right now, I'll post an answer later

I posted an answer below

First you have to make sure that the pattern(s) match the file extension you're using :
paths:
 - '**.tar'
 - '**.tgz'

You can match several patterns this way.
For the Node.js 16 warning, you can update to the v4 version of the checkout action.
Lastly, regarding the exctracted files : your workflow runs in a separate environment, that's why at the start you have to checkout the code : it doesn't exist yet. You can create folders, files, and run all kinds of programs / script but at the end nothing is saved.
If you want to extract the files from the archive and push them to your repo, you can first use your "Extract tgz files" step, then use git add [your files], git commit and then git push origin [your branch].
You can also use the upload-artifact action to upload your folder to Github :
- name: Upload folder
  uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
  with:
       name: Extracted archive
       path: src/

